# Openmp performance with omp_get_max_threads greater than number of cores

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I am novice is parallel programming. I running a my own Gibbs sampler written in C++. The overview of program look some thing like this.

```
 for(int iter=0; iter <=itermax; iter++){ //loop1
 #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) 
 for(int jobs= 0;  jobs<=1000; jobs++){ // loop2
     small_job();
     #pragma omp critical(dataupdate){
        data_updates()
     }
 } 
   jobs_that_cannot_be_parallelized();
}
```

I am running in a machine with 64 cores. Since small_job are of variable length and small I was assigning  omp_get_max_threads = 128. The number of cores used seems to be correct (see fig load last hour).[image: number of threads]. Each of peaks belongs to loop2.

However when I look to the actual cpu usage (see fig [image: cpu usage] it seems lot of of cpu is used by system and only 20% is used by user. Is it because I am spawning lots of threads at loop2. What are best practices to decide on  omp_get_max_threads? I know I have not given enough information but I will really appreciate any other recommendation to make the program faster.

Comment: Why not switch to OpenMP's `task`s? How big is `data_updates`, can you reduce it or store data to different places for each small job and combine them later? High system load is strange (do you have any I/O here?), and loop2 basically should not create too lot threads.

Comment: @osgx data_updates are just writing to a public array ( the size of array is big) compared to that each small_job are big. What would be advantage of using task considering small_job reads from multiple public array. There are no I/o in data update. Do you mean storing data of small_job in hard disk? If not, I am not sure how to store different data from small_job in variable exclusive to each small_job except a common public array (for which critical is needed). I will really appreciate if you can point me to an example.

Comment: What is your compiler and omp library (gcc + libgomp; icc + intel omp library or ??) If it is gcc+libgomp, try to set several environment variables and rerun with omp thread count equal to cpu count: `export GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0-63"` and `export OMP_WAIT_POLICY=ACTIVE`. (for I/O i mean only cause of high system load; for small_job results I mean that `omp critical` is bad for performance, while `omp atomic` and `omp reduce` are better, and the best possibly is to write result of job number I to some array into `array[I]`; for tasks I mean that omp task may be better for variable jobs than for)

Comment: what osgx is trying to say is that a `omp critical` + an update can usually be enhanced into a `omp reduce`. For instance, if you have a parallel for, in which you have a short job, followed by a critical that does a sum (or any other update operation), you can combine them into a parallel for reduction (you can write your custom reduction if you want).